# Requirements for google drive Share file Dialog

Tags: google-drive-api

Can someone here explain this part of [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing)?

> For the dialog to work as expected, all of the following must be true:
>
> 1. The user is signed in to Google
> 2. The user has installed your app The
> 3. URL of the page that launches the dialog must have the same origin as
>      the Open URL registered for the app.

specially the 2 and 3.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

your item 2 is explained in here https://developers.google.com/drive/install

item 3 is the "open url" you specify under the Drive SDK tab of the api console https://code.google.com/apis/console