# Google Drive Share Dialog Error - 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

UPDATE: We found an answer to this and posted it below, sorry for the duh moment..

I am getting the following error when opening the Share Dialog within a Google Drive Javascript app.

```
Refused to display 'https://drive.google.com/share?id=..
  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I think it is because the Open URL for the app is set to a launch server, but then we redirect another server for load balancing purposes. The requirements are referenced here: [Requirements for google drive Share file Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755222/requirements-for-google-drive-share-file-dialog).

For performance reasons, our load balancing servers use a different 3rd level domain. So for example, the Open URL within Drive points to a single server:

```
https://app.domain.com/app
```

This server then redirects to one of the following in order to distribute the load:

```
https://app01.domain.com/app
https://app02.domain.com/app
https://app03.domain.com/app
```

We need to distribute the load because our app has a real-time back end component that is resource intensive. I wish we could think of a better way to distribute users across servers, but that is the best we could come up with.

Can anyone suggest a better distribution method that would preserve the domain of origin? OR Is there any possible way to circumvent this same origin requirement. It would be really nice to be able to use the share dialog inside the app.

By the way, the Picker dialog works just fine. It does throw an error in the console, however..

```
Unable to post message to https://docs.google.com..
  Recipient has origin https://app01.domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

We found a workaround. We send all clients to the main URL for static content, which is not as big a concern from a loading perspective. Then we distributed the back end services across multiple servers. This may work for a good while.

The XMLHttpRequest object required that we add a CORS filter to the back end, but that was easy and we can control it ourselves.

Sorry for the bother..I am leaving question in case it helps clarify issue for others. I had to search for a while to figure out the cause, because there is a lot of bad advice out there.